# How to check if a point is a duplicate best practice?

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have a dataset where it is necessary to increment the timestamp by a nanosecond to avoid that my point is seen as a duplicate. (Got advice from [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-does-influxdb-handle-duplicate-points))

What is the best way of checking if a point with a certain tag set and timestamp already exists in the database?

At the moment I do it like this:

```
def duplicate_point(influxdb_client, influxdb_point):
    q = "SELECT * FROM random_measurement WHERE time={} AND mac='{}'".format(
        influxdb_point['time'],
        influxdb_point['tags']['mac']
    )
    result = influxdb_client.query(q)
    return bool(result)
```

If the result is not empty then the given point is a duplicate. When a duplicate is found a nanosecond is added to the timestamp. I do this check every time a point has to be written to the database but it has a huge impact on the throughput. Does there exist a better way of handeling this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can add an ID/serial number to your database, so all the entries have a different ID and won't be considered duplicates even if the other fields are equal. In fact, that is the other option mentioned in the documentation link you provided.

Comment: @Poshi I've tried that but my series cardinality gets way too high that is why I went for the second option.

Comment: Higher than a 64bit integer? In that case, just use a random number. There are very low chances that you choose the same number twice for the same timestamp. Assuming even a small 16 bit integer, the chances of hitting twice the same value are 1/(2**16)==0,001525879%

Comment: BTW, if you follow the "add nanosecond" path, your query should be more complex: given the fact that you can have multiple hits at the same timestamp, you should check if TS+1 is already used, and TS+2, and so on until you find an empty spot.

Comment: Thanks for reminding met that I need to check for TS+1. 

With the series cardinality I mean that I have more than 3 million different devices, picking this device as tag creates more than 3 million series which results in needing very high resources.

Comment: With 32 bits you can count up to almost 4295 millions. And with 64... square that number. You should have pretty much different numbers as needed.
In any case, you don't really need to have a different number per entry, just different numbers per each entries grup with the same TS. And a random number should work for that.

Comment: It is not about how I construct a unique tag. It is about how many unique tag values I can have. In my case I should need a InfluxDB instance with 32gb ram and 8 cores just for 3 days of data because I have to many series if I tag mac address aa unique tag.